# symfony2 and Doctrine2 - upload as a service

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning Symfony2 and need some advice. I have two entities, the first entity "Issue" has a OneToMany relationship with the second entity "Attachment". When posting an Issue form I am successfully uploading all child attachments, everything works hunky-dory :) but now I want to turn my upload solution into a service and that's where I'm getting confused. The uploads are processed in my Attachment model and my controller simply reads as follows :

```
    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();            

    ....
```

From what I understand a service can be accessed from a controller using the "get" method but because I do not process my attachments in the controller and never instantiate the "Attachment" model from the controller how do I pass it an upload service? Instantiating it within the Attachment entity construct appears to defeat the object of the exercise doesn't it?

Forgive me if I am talking rubbish. Idiot friendly guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT:: Further to the feedback, should uploads be treated as a service processed in the controller or could they be a behaviour associated to a model? Which way to jump.

Comment: it's possibly not what you're shooting for but i like to use the [Uploadable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md) Doctrine behavior and/or [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) for processing my uploads

Comment: Superb! Thanks, exactly the type of solution I am looking for. Of course, it was a doctrine question not really a symfony question. I shall see what they have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in ZF2 - but I use my controller still to process and receive the upload, then use the Service to extract the uploads, register them into the database etc.

I get the name of the file where it's temporarily uploaded to and pass that through to the service (i.e /tmp/up2029398393). That then moves it to where it's supposed to be, creates the entity and does the persist & flush for that object

Comment: Do you think it is correct to process them in the controller? Am I fundamentally wrong to have black-boxed the functionality into the entity?